# PHP: how to update json fields

Tags: php, json

I am passing three arguments to update a record stored in json file.
The records are dynamically created and saved according to the user's wish.
The following code successfully finds the id in the json file but fails in updating the record.
Please help me to complete the update task!!

```
//<$_GET sid desired ID, gid name of the json file to search in, and $nam array of new values>

$jsonitem = file_get_contents("folder1/".$gid.".txt");
$objitems= jsonp_decode($jsonitem,true);
foreach ($objitems as $row) {
    if ($row['id']==$sid) {
        $i=0;
        foreach ($row as $field => $value){
            $field->value = $nam[$i]; //this statement does not save the new values in the array!!
            $i++;
        }   
    }
}
$jsondata = json_encode($objitems,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$jsondata = "jsonp(" . $jsondata . ")";
file_put_contents("folder1/".$gid.".txt", $jsondata);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't updating $objitems in the foreach loop.. and you are using that variable in the json_encode

Replace `$field->value = $nam[$i];` with the appropriate $objitems variable array.

The code would be something like this :

```
<?php

$jsonitem = file_get_contents("folder1/".$gid.".txt");
$objitems= jsonp_decode($jsonitem,true);
$c=0;
foreach ($objitems as $row) 
{
    if ($row['id']==$sid) {
        $i=0;
        foreach ($row as $field => $value)
        {
            $row[$field][$value] = $nam[$i];
            $i++;
        }   
        $objitems[$c] = $row;
    }
    $c++;
}
$jsondata = json_encode($objitems,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$jsondata = "jsonp(" . $jsondata . ")";
file_put_contents("folder1/".$gid.".txt", $jsondata);
```

Comment: @Shubair I edited the answer to add some code for your reference.. check it.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent, This record is before running the code:
[..{
        "id": "1a",
        "Name": "shubair ",
        "Mark1": "100",
        "Mark2": "100",
        "Mark3": "100",
        "Mark4": "100",
        "Mark5": "100",
        "Mark6": "100"
    }, ..]

I called the function with arguments: gid=<jsonfilename>, sid="1a", and nam=array(0,1,..7). It replaces one character from each field [... {"id": "10","Name": "1hubair ","Mark1": "100      2", "Mark2": "100      3","Mark3": "100      4", "Mark4": "100      5", "Mark5": "100      6", "Mark6": "100      7" }, ..]

Comment: This is what I see exactly my dears. The main issue in my case is the field number and filed name are variables.

Comment: based on my example, the id field should be replaced with "0", name field with "1", mark1 field with "2" ...  and so on. Currently, the code only replaces (or adds) one character from the field values. I need to reformat this statement: $row[$field][$value] = $nam[$i];